# Key strokes in wpf window hosted in MFC ActiveX running in Internet Explorer

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, mfc, activex

We have an MFC ActiveX control created in Visual Studio 2008 with CLR support which creates a WPF grid and shows a WPF window within that grid.

This ActiveX is hosted within Internet Explorer and it shows up and works nicely except that the tab key, backspace, function keys etc. does not work since they are handeled by IE instead of the WPF window. Regular characters works nicely. This is a known feature and previously when we used to have MFC based dialogs within this ActiveX we used this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187988. By just using this code directly the

```
AfxGetApp()->PreTranslateMessage((LPMSG)lParam)
```

statement will return FALSE, so I'm not able to get the key stroke to be handled by the WPF window. I beleive I need to ask the WPF application this instead of the CWinApp, but I'm not sure how and if this can be done. Does anyone have enough understanding of what's going on here to get this to work?

Using XBAP instead of ActiveX is not an option as this is run in an intranet application which needs more access than the sandbox can give us.

I hope this is enough information.

With best regards

Svein Dybvik

Answer (score 2):

We have hosted a WPF user control inside an MFC modeless dialog.  In order to get some keyboard stuff working correctly, we had to modify the dialogs PreTranslateMessage() function.

Basically, what we did was to check to see if the message was for the WPF window.  If it was, we immediately call TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage and then return TRUE from PreTranslateMessage.

Our WPF control fills the entire dialog, so you'd have to have your own conditional check where we have the IsChild test.

```
BOOL CHostDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
   // normal PreTranslateMessage() causes the edit fields not to work
   if (::IsChild(GetSafeHwnd(), pMsg->hwnd))
   {
      TranslateMessage(pMsg);
      DispatchMessage(pMsg);

      return TRUE;
   }

   return baseclass::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some edit:

```
BOOL CHostDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
    {
       // normal PreTranslateMessage() causes the edit fields not to work
       if (::IsChild(GetSafeHwnd(), pMsg->hwnd))
       {
          TranslateMessage(pMsg);
          DispatchMessage(pMsg);
          pMsg->hwnd = GetSafeHwnd(); // redirect to parent
       }
       return baseclass::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
    }
```